# maven-release-plugin does not work for multi-module POMs

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

**Plugin version:** 2.0

I am trying to use the maven-release-plugin to set the version of the parent POM and all modules.

Using the following parent POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>uk.co.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
    <version>latest-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>My Project</name>

    <modules>
        <module>../../subPom1</module>
        <module>../../subPom2</module>
            <module>../../subPom3</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <id>set-release-versions</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <developmentVersion>1.1.8</developmentVersion>
                            <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When running `mvn clean install -DskipTests -Pdeploy`, the configuration to run the plugin on the clean phase is totally ignored and the build is made using the value "latest-SNAPSHOT".

I was expecting it to pick up the value "1.1.8" from the plugin configuration.

Each child POM is equivalent to:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>uk.co.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
        <version>latest-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../../System/build/parentPom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    ...

</project>
```

Why is the configuration ignored?

**Edit #1:** Filesystem structure as requested:

```
/
 |- system
 |  |
 |  |- build
 |      |
 |      |-parentPOM file
 |
 |- business
 |     |
 |     | - childPOM1
 |     | - childPOM2
 |- client
 |     | - childPOM3
 |     | - childPOM4
```

Ignore the .../... in the SSCCE - I have obfuscated the true values to describe the problem generically.

**Edit #2:** I have moved the definition to `<pluginManagement>` as advised but the problem remains the same (not using plugin, no feedback to console):

```
<pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <developmentVersion>1.1.8</developmentVersion>
                        <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
```

Comment: First you should update the version of the [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) to 2.4.1 instead of 2.0 (which is really old). Is it possible to show the folder structure of your project? Ah. Why have you bound the maven-release-plugin to the clean phase? That does not make sense?

Comment: Hi. I assumed that I should get it to run right at the beginning, so I bound it to 'clean'. I'm throttled to use 2.0 I'm afraid. Each project is a seperate folder in my Eclipse environment. I should add that this build constructs JARs and a WAR into an EAR fine - it is just that this plugin is not binding to any goal and is consequently being entirely ignored.

Comment: For such purposes you should use pluginManagement to configure such things as you described. But you really need to update the version, cause the old one has bugs. That each project has is a separate Eclipse project is ok. But furthermore i see that you are using `parentPoml.xml` as parent and different levels which looks not very good. Is there a good reason having such different levels of relationships?

Comment: Structure added as requested. No good reason for it to be laid out as it is other than for legacy reasons. It wouldn't be my choice however the paths to each child are being resolved to complete the build without errors - it is just that the maven-release-plugin is not subscribed to a goal and is not firing.

Comment: I have moved the configuration to pluginManagement as advised however the problem remains. The documentation for the plugin is awful - no example using POM configuration is given.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to set the goal of the plugin. You configured the parameter needed for the update-versions goal but you told maven only to execute the plugin in the clean phase, but not which goal of the plugin. So it does nothing at all.

Check the maven log when you try a mvn clean it should only show:

```
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ test ---
```

When you change your config to:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>clean</phase>
                    <id>set-release-versions</id>
                    <goals><goal>update-versions</goal></goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <developmentVersion>1.1.8</developmentVersion>
                        <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The goal update-versions is called in the clean phase of maven.

```
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.0:update-versions (set-release-versions) @ bdd ---
```

Not sure if this will solve all your problems but this will force maven to execute the plugin in the clean phase like expected.

However the release plugin needs a lot of special settings (like a scm connection) when used for only changing the version. So I suggest to use the [versions-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html)

```
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>set</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>clean</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <newVersion>1.1.8</newVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Hopefully this will take its place on the web and serve as a template for the plugin for others to follow! Your advice to instead use versions-maven-plugin for versioning is certainly consistent with the advice given in other forums and I shall look into using this plugin.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I gave up.

That Stack Overflow et all is littered with unanswered questions just like this one, and that the plugin documentation fails to provide usage examples in POM format, tells me everything that I need to know about this plugin.

My workaround was to set the parent POM's version to "latest-SNAPSHOT" and introduce a property called `<myproject.release.version>,` which I used everywhere that I wanted to print the release number.

In particular, I wanted to print the release number in the WAR file's manifest. I did so as below:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                    <archive>
                          <manifest>
                               <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                            </manifest>
                           <manifestEntries>
                                    <Implementation-Version>${myproject.release.version}</Implementation-Version>
                                </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>war</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>war</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
                            <filters>
                                <filter>${project.parent.basedir}/filter/${webapp.filter}.properties</filter>
                            </filters>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
 </plugin>
```

Using the above configuration, I drop the release number, as a Maven property, into my manifest.

In my application, I pick it up from there and draw it on the screen.